# PySpark DataFrame show() method causing Py4J TypeError during user-defined function execution

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a PySpark DataFrame with a user-defined function (compute_simplicity) that computes simplicity for text data and then adds the calculated value into the main DataFrame. The function looks like this:

```
def compute_simplicity(text, common_word_list):
    words = word_tokenize(text)  # Tokenize the text
    common_words = [word.lower() for word in words if word.lower() in common_word_list]

    percentage_common = (len(common_words) / len(words)) * 100
    print(percentage_common)
    return percentage_common

compute_simplicity_udf = F.udf(lambda x: compute_simplicity(x, common_word_list=broadcast_common_word_list.value), FloatType())
combined_df = combined_df.withColumn("simplicity", compute_simplicity_udf("content"))
combined_df.show()
```

However, when I try to display the DataFrame using the show() method, I encounter the following Py4J TypeError:

```
2024-02-18 12:02:23,566:INFO:Closing down client-server connection
2024-02-18 12:02:24,123:DEBUG:Exception while garbage collecting an object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Documents/workspace/projects/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 647, in _garbage_collect_object
    smart_decode(gateway_client.address) +
  File "/Users/projects/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 215, in smart_decode
    if isinstance(s, unicode):
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

I'm unsure why this error is happening during the execution of the user-defined function. Has anyone experienced a similar issue when using PySpark DataFrame with a UDF involving external libraries like PyTorch and GPT-2? Any suggestions on how to resolve or debug this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I add `from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize` to the udf your code works for me. Do you get an error if you call `compute_simplicity` directly (`compute_simplicity('this is hello world', ['this', 'is'])`)? If you have more than one Spark node, did you install nltk on all nodes?